# Formula that will duplicate certain cells (2 ranges of cells) in a row & place in the next row according to a # in a cell from 2-20

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

It sounds confusing. I am entering futures trades in a log. Sometimes those trades (like one trade) is/are copied multiple times and taken all at once in groups or batches/same trade but several accounts, but it needs to be entered as separate line items (separate trades) in order to get the broad picture with profit and risk. Therefore, I am looking to have a small cell where I type the number of times the entry (which is a couple of different ranges of cells on the row) needs to be duplicated onto the next row and possibly the next depending on what number I put in the cell which could be anywhere from 2 to 20. So I basically need the row duplicated X number of times but not the entire row, just a couple of sections of cells of that row where I have to enter data. Not every entry will be duplicated, sometimes only one account is traded. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)? Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.